# Definition of a Gaussian random process in the vectorial case.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm studying Gaussian random processes because I need them in order to understand Kalman filtering. I can understand the definition of a Gaussian random process in the scalar case.

For what I have understood a scalar process $X(t)$ is called Gaussian if, for any sequence of instants $t_{1}, t_{2}, \ldots,t_{n}$, and whatever $n$, the random variables $X(t_{1}), X(t_{2}),\ldots,X(t_{n})$ extracted at those instants of time are **jointly** Gaussian, i.e., their joint p.d.f is a n-variate Gaussian p.d.f.

Since in Kalman filtering processes involved are often **vector-valued** I also searched for a definition valid in the vectorial case. The one that I found is similar to the one reported above expect for the fact that every random variable $X(t_{i})$ is substituted with a random vector $\mathbf{X}(t_{i})$.

My question is, then, when are $n$ random vectors $\mathbf{X}(t_{1}), \mathbf{X}(t_{2}),\ldots,\mathbf{X}(t_{n})$, extracted from the vector-valued random process $\mathbf{X}(t)$, considered jointly Gaussian? Do I have to consider all the components of each vector as random variables and consider the joint p.d.f. of all the random variables extracted from each random vector?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do just consider the all of the components at all of the times as being a sample from a multivariate normal distribution, that is for each $t_m$, $t_n$ of your input set and each component $i,j$ of the vectors $\mathbf{X}(t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^D$ you specify the first two moments
$$
\begin{align*}
m^{i}(t_n) &:= \mathbb{E}\left[ X^i(t_n)\right] \\
k^{ij}(t_n,t_m) &:= \mbox{Cov}\left\{ X^{i}(t_n), X^{j}(t_m)\right\}
\end{align*}
$$
this defines a mean ''array'' of shape $(n , D)$ and a covariance array of shape $(n \cdot D  ,n \cdot D)$, but you can ravel these vectors to recast it as the scalar problem you are more familiar with, i.e. a sample of size $n \cdot D$ from a multivariate normal.

Comment: Goes without saying that the function $k^{ij}(s, t)$ should be defined so that the resulting $(n\cdot D ) \times (n \cdot D)$ 'covariance matrix' is indeed a valid covariance matrix

Comment: Thank you @Nadiels. Just some doubts. Why is not the mean array a regular column vector of shape $(n \cdot D, 1)$? Also is it correct that, while evaluating the 'covariance matrix', $t_n$ can also be equal to $t_m$ (i.e. the covariance between components of the same vector is considered)? I cannot upvote because my reputation is < 15!

Comment: Yeah absolutely on both, that is what I meant by raveling the mean function, typically you would define such a function that takes $t \mapsto x \in \mathbb{R}^D$, giving the $n \times D$ shape, but in the obvious way you can consider that as the corresponding col. vector. And yes the case $t_n = t_m$ is a special case - the marginal distribution of $\mathbf{X}(t_n)$ - and should be a properly defined multivariate normal itself.